Saving Game with Google Play Game Services gives error saying Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console
I have integrated Google Play Game services in my android app, the login works fine and now I am trying to save my game but when I try to do so I get error saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console, I have enabled 'Saved Game' in Google play console, refer to below screenshot


When I was going through the doc, I noticed that it requires GoogleSignInClient as well before using saved games, now given that GoogleSignInClient is deprecated I am using credential manager, please do not confuse this with Google play game services sign in which I already do as soon as the app is opened by following this doc
So I decided to use credential manager with google drive access, here is the sample code for it
private fun signInSilently() {

        val credentialManager = CredentialManager.create(this)

        val rawNonce = UUID.randomUUID().toString()
        val bytes = rawNonce.toByteArray()
        val md = MessageDigest.getInstance("SHA-256")
        val digest = md.digest(bytes)
        val hashedNonce = digest.fold("") { str, it -> str + "%02x".format(it) }

        val googleIdOption = GetGoogleIdOption.Builder()
            .setFilterByAuthorizedAccounts(false) //IMP Part
            .setServerClientId("MY_WEB_CLIENT_ID")
            .setAutoSelectEnabled(true)
            .setNonce(hashedNonce)
            .build()


        val request: GetCredentialRequest = GetCredentialRequest.Builder()
            .addCredentialOption(googleIdOption)
            .build()

        lifecycleScope.launch {
            try {
                val result = credentialManager.getCredential(
                    request = request,
                    context = this@MainActivity,
                )

                handleSignIn(result)
            } catch (e: GetCredentialException) {
                Log.e("Erroris", "Error getting credential", e)
            }
        }

    }

    private fun handleSignIn(result: GetCredentialResponse) {
        // Handle the successfully returned credential.
        when (val credential = result.credential) {

            // Passkey credential
            is PublicKeyCredential -> {
                // Share responseJson such as a GetCredentialResponse on your server to
                // validate and authenticate
                val responseJson = credential.authenticationResponseJson
            }

            // Password credential
            is PasswordCredential -> {
                // Send ID and password to your server to validate and authenticate.
                val username = credential.id
                val password = credential.password
            }

            // GoogleIdToken credential
            is CustomCredential -> {
                if (credential.type == GoogleIdTokenCredential.TYPE_GOOGLE_ID_TOKEN_CREDENTIAL) {
                    try {
                        // Use googleIdTokenCredential and extract id to validate and
                        // authenticate on your server.
                        val googleIdTokenCredential = GoogleIdTokenCredential
                            .createFrom(credential.data)
                        val googleIdToken = googleIdTokenCredential.idToken
                        Log.i("answer", googleIdToken)
                        val personId = googleIdTokenCredential.id
                        Log.i("answer", personId) //email
                        val displayName = googleIdTokenCredential.displayName
                        Log.i("answer", displayName.toString())
                        val personPhoto = googleIdTokenCredential.profilePictureUri
                        Log.i("answer", personPhoto.toString())

                        val requestedScopes = listOf(Scope(DriveScopes.DRIVE_APPDATA))
                        val authorizationRequest =
                            AuthorizationRequest.builder()
                                .setRequestedScopes(requestedScopes)
                                .build()

                        Identity.getAuthorizationClient(this@MainActivity)
                            .authorize(authorizationRequest)
                            .addOnSuccessListener {
                                if (it.hasResolution()) {
                                    val pendingIntent = it.pendingIntent
                                    val intentSenderRequest = pendingIntent?.intentSender?.let { it1 ->
                                        IntentSenderRequest.Builder(
                                            it1
                                        ).build()
                                    }
                                    intentSenderRequest?.let { it1 -> authorizationLauncher.launch(it1) }
                                } else {

                                    Toast.makeText(
                                        this@MainActivity,
                                        "Access already granted ",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                                    ).show()
                                }
                            }.addOnFailureListener {
                                Toast.makeText(this@MainActivity, "Failure ${it.message}", Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                                    .show()
                            }

                    } catch (e: GoogleIdTokenParsingException) {
                        Log.e("Erroris", "Received an invalid google id token response", e)
                    }
                } else {
                    // Catch any unrecognized custom credential type here.
                    Log.e("Erroris", "Unexpected type of credential")
                }
            }

            else -> {
                // Catch any unrecognized credential type here.
                Log.e("Erroris", "Unexpected type of credential")
            }
        }
    }

Once this is successful then I call the below code to save my game
 val snapshotsClient =
                PlayGames.getSnapshotsClient(this)
            val maxNumberOfSavedGamesToShow = 5

            val intentTask = snapshotsClient.getSelectSnapshotIntent(
                "See My Saves", true, true, maxNumberOfSavedGamesToShow
            )
            intentTask.addOnCompleteListener {
                if (intentTask.isSuccessful) {
                    savedGameLauncher.launch(intentTask.result)
                } else {
                    Log.i("here123","${it.exception}")
                    Toast.makeText(this, "Fail to get snapshot", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                }
            }


private val savedGameLauncher = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.StartActivityForResult()) { result ->
        val intent = result.data

        if(intent != null){

            val snapshotsClient =
                PlayGames.getSnapshotsClient(this)

            if (intent.hasExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_METADATA)) {
                // Load a snapshot.
                //TODO display progress bar
                val snapshotMetadata = if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.TIRAMISU) {
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_METADATA, SnapshotMetadata::class.java)
                } else {
                    intent.getParcelableExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_METADATA)
                }

                val mCurrentSaveName = snapshotMetadata!!.uniqueName
                val conflictResolutionPolicy =
                    SnapshotsClient.RESOLUTION_POLICY_MOST_RECENTLY_MODIFIED


                snapshotsClient.open(mCurrentSaveName,true,conflictResolutionPolicy)
                    .addOnFailureListener {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Save Game Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                    }
                    .continueWith {
                        val snapshot = it.result.data
                        if(snapshot != null){
                            val byteArray = snapshot.snapshotContents.readFully()
                            val stringData = String(byteArray)
                            Log.i("datais",stringData)
                            Toast.makeText(this, stringData, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }
                    .addOnCompleteListener{
                   //TODO dismiss progress bar
                }



            } else if (intent.hasExtra(SnapshotsClient.EXTRA_SNAPSHOT_NEW)) {
                // Create a new snapshot named with a unique string
                val unique: String = BigInteger(281, Random()).toString(13)
                val mCurrentSaveName = "snapshotTemp-$unique"

                snapshotsClient.open(mCurrentSaveName,true).addOnCompleteListener{
                        if(it.isSuccessful){
                            val snapshot = it.result.data
                            val stringData = "Level 100"

                            if(snapshot != null){
                                snapshot.snapshotContents.writeBytes(stringData.toByteArray())

                                val metadataChange = SnapshotMetadataChange.Builder().setDescription("$stringData reached").build()

                                snapshotsClient.commitAndClose(snapshot, metadataChange).addOnCompleteListener{ finalResult ->
                                    if(finalResult.isSuccessful){
                                        Toast.makeText(this, "Save Game Success", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                                    }
                                }
                            } else {
                                Toast.makeText(this, "Snapshot is null", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                            }


                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(this, "Save Game Fail", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
                        }
                    }

            }
        }



    }

but I keep seeing error saying java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot use snapshots without enabling the 'Saved Game' feature in the Play console, I even waited for a day thinking it might take some time to propagate the changes on Google server side but unfortunately waiting does not work

hey i think  it may take up to 24 hours for Google Play games services to activate the Saved Games feature for your game. If you want to test the Saved Games feature immediately, manually clear the data in the Google Play Services app installed on your test device.
checkout this : https://developer.android.com/games/pgs/console/enable-features

I have waited for a week now but still same issue
